# Listbox is empty after binding it to a data source (SQL Server database): C#, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

Whenever I insert values into my forms textboxes and carry that information over to the next form, the listbox to which the data should be bound to is empty. I have explicitly stated which input values from the previous form should appear in the listbox, but nothing seems to happen.

I am basically trying to store data in the same database at different times throughout the app. Below is the code related to the issue.

**Properties**

```
public class AccountInfo
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string surname { get; set; }
   public string email { get ; set; }
   public string password { get; set; }
   public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
   public string cardType { get; set; }
   public string cardNumber { get; set; }
   public string expiryDate { get; set; }
   public string ccv { get; set; }
   public string duration { get; set; }

   public string FullInfo
   {
      get
      {
         email = Form1.SetValueForText1;
         return $" {name} {surname} ({ email }) ({dateOfBirth}) ({cardType}) ({cardNumber}) ({expiryDate}) ({duration})";
      }
    }
}
```

This function inserts values into the database

```
public void InsertNewCardDetails(string card_Type, string card_Number, string expiry_date, string _ccv, string _duration)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nauri\source\repos\StylistsApp\Database\UserAccountDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
    {
        List<AccountInfo> accounts = new List<AccountInfo>();
        accounts.Add(new AccountInfo {cardType = card_Type, cardNumber = card_Number, expiryDate = expiry_date, ccv = _ccv, duration = _duration });
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO[Table] (cardType, cardNumber, expiryDate, ccv, duration) VALUES(@cardType, @cardNumber, @expiryDate, @ccv, @duration)", accounts);
    }
}
```

Binding data to input fields

```
namespace StylistsApp
{
    public partial class CardDetails : Form
    {
        public CardDetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
            SetValueForCardType = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
            SetValueForCardNumber = textBox5.Text;
            SetValueForExpiryDate = textBox2.Text;
            SetValueForCCV = textBox3.Text;
            SetValueForDuration = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            db.InsertNewCardDetails(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), textBox5.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show("Account Created Successfully!");

            this.Close();
            Summary summary = new Summary();
            summary.Show();
        }    

        public static string SetValueForCardType = "";
        public static string SetValueForCardNumber = "";
        public static string SetValueForExpiryDate = "";
        public static string SetValueForCCV = "";
        public static string SetValueForDuration = "";
    }
}
```

Attempting to bind data from previous form to the current forms listbox. If `this.listBox1.DataSource = null;` and `this.listBox1.Items.Clear();`  are removed, the program throws a

> System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

on the line

```
this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Code:

```
    public partial class Summary : Form
    {
        List<AccountInfo> people = new List<AccountInfo>();
        //private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();
        public Summary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Summary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nauri\source\repos\StylistsApp\Database\UserAccountDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            sql.Open();
            SqlCommand sqa = new SqlCommand("Select cardType, cardNumber, expiryDate, ccv, duration from [Table] where email =@email", sql);
            sqa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Form1.SetValueForText1);        
            SqlDataReader da = sqa.ExecuteReader();
            
            while (da.Read())
            {
                this.listBox1.DataSource = null;
                this.listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
     
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(1).ToString());
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(2).ToString());
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(3).ToString());
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(da.GetValue(4).ToString());
            }
            sql.Close();
        }
    }
```

The outcome is shown in this screenshot [image: Outcome]

Any ideas? Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked what does GetValue return?

Comment: Yes, it returns the property value of the specified object. So index 0...4 would return whatever is stored in sqa (cardType, cardNumber, expiryDate, ccv etc..).

Comment: What's the value in this.listBox1.Items[0]?

Comment: No clue, it doesn't say

Comment: Well... put a breakpoint in you code and view in there

Comment: Yes I already did that. When I hover over .GetValue(0) there is no entry after picking a value from a combobox.

Comment: this is all I get when i hover over it ```{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader}```

Comment: Don't hover, debug!

Comment: I have already solved the issue. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to store data in the same database at different points throughout an app, create a seperate database. It will save you a headache.